# Why am I reading only zeroes from PORTB?

Tags: atmega328, pins

I am using a custom Arduino Nano compatible board with an Atmel 328P.  I am externally changing the values applied to several pins on PORTB.  I expect to be able to read the values of these pins (low or high) but I always read zeroes.  However, the pin change interrupt is called.  What do I need to do to read values from PORTB?

Supply voltage is 5 volts.  Pin applied high voltage is 3.3 volts.

With the below code, when I change the voltage applied to a pin, LED1 flashes but LED2 does not.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define LED1_PORT                           (PORTD)
#define LED1_PIN_bm                         (_BV(4))         //D1, white

#define LED2_PORT                           (PORTD)
#define LED2_PIN_bm                         (_BV(3))         //D2, red

volatile bool g_bValueChanged = 0;

void setup()
{
  DDRB = 0;                     //set all as inputs
  PCMSK0 = 0xfb;                //exclude 1 pin because of noise
  PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);        //enable pin change interrupt 0 (for pins PB0..7)

  sei();
}

uint8_t g_valuePrevious = 0;

void loop()
{
  if (g_bValueChanged)
  {
    g_bValueChanged = false;

    LED1_PORT |= LED1_PIN_bm;
    delay(40);
    LED1_PORT &= ~LED1_PIN_bm;
    delay(40);
  }

  uint8_t value = PORTB;
  if (value != g_valuePrevious)
  {
    g_valuePrevious = value;
    
    LED2_PORT |= LED2_PIN_bm;
    delay(40);
    LED2_PORT &= ~LED2_PIN_bm;
    delay(40);
  }
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
    g_bValueChanged = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PORTB` register is initialized by the hardware to zero. You never
write to this register, so it always stays zero.

Maybe you are mixing up `PORTB` and `PINB`:

- `PORTB` is the port **output** register, controlled by you
- `PINB` is the port **input** register, for which the bits
  corresponding to input pins are controlled by whatever drives those
  pins from the outside.

Comment: I am applying a signal to those pins externally.  I have been programming XMega which uses the same PORTB for input and output.  Now I see PINB in the datasheet, you are probably correct, I will try it.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that is what I understood from reading your question.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer, I was not aware that the processor I am using had different registers for input and output.

Comment: Different registers, indeed. And there is even a free goodie: if you attempt to _write_ to the port _input_ registers, you get toggle functionality: for every bit you write to one, the corresponding output pin is toggled.